# Multiplying binomials

Tags: c

I am asking again, because before my question was unclear. 
So I need to make a program for my college which will calculate Lagrange poynomial ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)) and write out polynomial p(x)

```
(like x^2 + 2x + 4 or just x^2)
```

And my question is: How I can calculate things like this -

```
(x+1)*(x-1)
```

and print  after calculating things like

```
x^2, 3x^3
```

? X is unknown and can't be declared as a number. Any ideas how I can make that?

Comment: what have you learned in class?

Comment: so tell me how to make that multyplying (x-1)x+1)=x^2-1 in c? I'll be glad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but I'll bite and take a shot at answering your question (even though it seems like you haven't put in any of the requisite effort yourself, it may be that you simply don't even know where to start).

In both of your questions (this one, and [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769267/c-multiply-unknows)) you've used the same example: `(x + 1) * (x - 1)` I think it would be ridiculous to ask a college student to write some sort of Mathematica-style symbolic manipulation system for homework... so I'm going to go out on a limb and assume the homework is really to write a program that will solve only functions specifically of the form: `(x + n) * (x + g)`

If that's the case, then this is a fairly straight-forward assignment.

The first think you need to realize is that you can represent this in polynomial form as such:

`x^2 + (n+g)x + ng`

So you can prompt the user for "n" and "g", then calculate `n+g` and `n*g` and simply print out the result in the above form.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 1;
    int g = -1;

    // Print Input:
    printf("(x %c %d)(x %c %d) = ", (n >= 0 ? '+' : '-'), (int)fabs(n), (g >= 0 ? '+' : '-'), (int)fabs(g));

    // Calculate Terms:
    int term2 = n + g;
    int term3 = n * g;

    // Print Result:
    printf("x^2");
    if (term2 != 0) { printf(" %c %dx", (term2 >= 0 ? '+' : '-'), (int)fabs(term2)); }
    if (term3 != 0) { printf(" %c %d", (term3 >= 0 ? '+' : '-'), (int)fabs(term3)); }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

For values n=1 and g=-1 the output of the above is: `x^2 - 1`

For values n=3 and g=5 the output of the above is: `x^2 + 8x + 15`

This seems to be inline with what you're looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't want to get a code, but it explains it better how to make that thing. Now I understand how to do it. Thenk you again! :)